# VCR ignored parameter: Get real http request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, vcr

I'm recording http requests with VCR for my test suite. I have to ignore a parameter called `callback` because the parameter is random, and I don't want VCR to record a new request when this parameter changes (because only the parameter changes, not the request itself).

But my problem is, that I need to modify the response body VCR is serving to my app, based on the original value of `callback` that my client generated at runtime.

Here is my VCR configuration:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/vcr_cassettes'
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = false
  c.ignore_localhost = true

  c.before_http_request(:stubbed?) do |request|
    # request.uri is the ORIGINAL request made by the client
    puts request.uri
  end

  c.before_playback do |interaction, cassette|
    # request uri got the value from the cassette
    interaction.request.uri
    # and here I want to modify the interaction.response.body
    # based on the callback parameter from the original request from the client
    interaction.response.body = "...."
  end

  # add the callback and no caching _ parameter to the ignored parameters
  c.default_cassette_options = {
    record: :once,
    match_requests_on: [:method, VCR.request_matchers.uri_without_params("callback", "_")]
  }
end
```

In the `c.before_http_request(:stubbed?)` callback, the real value of `callback` is in the `request.uri`. Then VCR ignores this parameter, and replays the former recorded cassette. In the `c.before_playback` callback, I can modify the `interaction.response.body`, but the `callback` parameter got the value from the cassette, when it was recorded.

How is it possible to get the **real** value of `callback` inside the `c.before_playback` callback? Because this callback is the only one that allows to modify the response body. I tried it out with `c.after_http_request(:stubbed?)` where I get the response body AND the real value of the `callback` parameter, but this hook is too late, because my app already received the response body.

Any monkeypatch, dirty hack or trick would be great!

Comment: does no one have a solution for this? I looked into the VCR gem sourcecode, but I haven't figured out how to do this. I searched for the place where VCR first recognizes the http request, but I haven't. I'm not sure, maybe the first place is the mocking framework, and VCR don't has any access to the real request from the client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on Github when someone put me into the right direction: https://github.com/nbibler/vcr-284